# implode function return implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Tags: laravel

I am implode some id, it works when array have at least 1 value. if array is null the implode function returns error as implode(): Invalid arguments passed

```
$arr=implode(',', $request->id);


 $product= DB::table('sub_categories')
        ->join('categories','sub_categories.category_id','=','categories.category_id')
        ->join('products','sub_categories.subcategory_id','=','products.subcategory_id')
         ->join('colors','colors.color_id','=','products.product_color')
         ->select('products.*','categories.category_name','sub_categories.subcategory_name','colors.*')
         ->whereRaw('color_id IN ('.$arr.')')
         ->where(strtolower('sub_categories.subcategory_slug'),$request->subcategory_id) 
        ->orderBy('products.product_name','ASC')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a default value to account for scenario when $request->id is null

```php
$arr = implode(',', $request->input('id', []));
```

Can do the whereIn conditionally in the query

````php
```php
$arr=implode(',', $request->input('id', []));


 $query= DB::table('sub_categories')
        ->join('categories','sub_categories.category_id','=','categories.category_id')
        ->join('products','sub_categories.subcategory_id','=','products.subcategory_id')
         ->join('colors','colors.color_id','=','products.product_color')
         ->select('products.*','categories.category_name','sub_categories.subcategory_name','colors.*')
         ->where(strtolower('sub_categories.subcategory_slug'),$request->subcategory_id);

if(!empty($arr)) {    
    $query->whereRaw('color_id IN ('.$arr.')');
}

$product = $query->orderBy('products.product_name','ASC')->get();
````

Comment: If the $request->input('id') returns null then the $arr will be an empty string so if you are using whereIn in a query then naturally it will give error. You need to have some defaults for the query as well otherwise whenever $request->input('id') is null query will give error. Or you can have a conditional in the query. If you can post the query code may be I can suggest

Comment: @seemapatil Have updated answer to include your query, let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

If the given data is not an array, then `implode()` function will throw a warning error.
To get rid of the error, you can check the array with **[is_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)** method:

```
if(is_array($request->id)){
   $arr = implode(',', $request->id);
} else {
   $arr = NULL;
}
```